# Where to define a QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to define a queryset. In the shell it is all fine and I can filter the column I want with:

```
pat1 = Patient.objects.get(pk=1)
pat1.examinationgeometry_set.filter(examination='FIRST')
```

now I want to define a QuerySet out of it but I don't know where to define it and how. In the Views, Templates, Models? And how do I write it? I know that I have to define it with a function but is there any function from django for it?

Idea behind this queryset is to show all of the results in my database from the first examination. So in my template I have sth like this:

```html
{% if Patient.examinationgeometry_set.filter(examination='FIRST') %}
 {% for geo in patient.examinationgeometry_set.all %}
   <li> x:  {{ geo.x }}<br/>
        c: {{ geo.c }}  <br/>
        b: {{ geo.b}}<br/>
        n: {{ geo.n}}<br/>
   </li>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: querysets are generally built in the view and passed onto the template

Comment: You can't use filter in templates. You have to make templatetags for filter data from model object. Otherwise send filtered data from view to templates

Comment: all logic relative to obtaining data should go in the views, in fact, it won't work in templates for this very reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querysets should be made in the view, not in the template, given your code, it should be something like this:

view.py:

```
def my_view:
  patients = Patient.objects.all()
  context = {"patients": patients}
  return render(request, "template_path", context)
```

template.html:

```
{% for patient in patients %}
  {% for geo in patient.examinationgeometry_set.all %}
    {% if geo.examination == 'FIRST' %}
      <li> 
          x:  {{ geo.x }}<br/>
          c: {{ geo.c }}<br/>
          b: {{ geo.b}}<br/>
          n: {{ geo.n}}<br/>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

A better option is to make a python property for your patient model like this:

```
class Patient(stuff):
  # your model stuff
  @property
  def first_examinationgeometry_set():
    # maybe this should use .get() instead of filter?
    return self.examinationgeometry_set.filter(examination="FIRST")
```

and now call this in the template(same view as first example):

```
{% for patient in patients %}
  {% with geo=patient.first_examinationgeometry_set %}
    <li> 
        x:  {{ geo.x }}<br/>
        c: {{ geo.c }}<br/>
        b: {{ geo.b}}<br/>
        n: {{ geo.n}}<br/>
    </li>
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The "another option" is of course the right one if you have any concern about maintainability and performances.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree, so i editted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and I have understood how to make the querys/filters in django.

Comment: please accept the answer and consider upvoting if this answer helped you ;)